# How not to give parent's css to child tag in NextJs and TailWindCSS

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, opacity

I have the following code:

```
<div className="py-8 bg-black opacity-50">
    <p className="text-white text-6xl text-center z-2 opacity-100">
        Our Promise
    </p>
</div>
```

I don't want to opacity in  effect on the

.

As you see, I gave z-index and opacity to

but nothing changes.

Comment: Maybe you want to use `bg-opacity-50` on the parent block instead? The current code will set opacity for all children and I'm not sure you can opt out of it in the child element. Use bg-opacity instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `opacity-50` You don't reduce the opacity of the color but reduce the opacity of the element (with all children).

What you're asking about is [`bg-black/50`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-color#changing-the-opacity)